# Animated dots in loading text

Tags: ios7

I want to do loading animation. When I tap the button text become "loading" then "loading." then "loading.." and from the beginning. How to do this?
I tried `[UIView animateWithDuration]` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Just have a timer call a method ever 1 second (or how ever long) and add a . to the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very difficult to achieve. Create a `NSTimer` property and then the start/stop/update methods like so:

```
- (void)startLoadingAnimation {
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Loading" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(updateLoadingLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateLoadingLabel {
    NSString *ellipses = @"...";

    if ([self.myButton.titleLabel.text rangeOfString:ellipses].location == NSNotFound) {
        [self.myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",self.myButton.titleLabel.text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.myButton setTitle:@"Loading" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (void)endLoadingAnimation {
    [self.myTimer invalidate];
    self.myTimer = nil;
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Loading" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

In this example the label is updated every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: thanks. it works but not as I expected. Old "loading" text disappears and new text appears and button title blinking. How to fix this? I can add label near the button and change only dots but is there any other way?

Comment: As of iOS 7, when you change the title of a UIButton it produces a blinking animation. To overcome this, you can either change the button type to Custom (or `UIButtonTypeCustom` programatically), or you can hide the button when tapped and replace it with a label until loading has finished.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm hiding button and show label and it works as I wanted!